# Feature detection of edges in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Are there any feature detectors that do a good job of matching images that have previously had an edge detection algorithm run over them?

The context of this question is that I have two images which are x-rays of a person's mouth, but taken at different times, such that: a). the new angle of the x-ray is slightly different. b). the teeth may have moved/changed slightly.

I am planning to use feature detection to then get a homography which will allow me to twist the second image to align with the first, so that I can then compare them.

Here is one of the images after using Canny edge detection:

[image: Dental X-ray]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions of feature detectors, or any suggestions on how else I might approach this problem.

Comment: Edge detection loses a lot of information in the image.  Most image alignment tools I've used work on the original images.  Is there a reason why you're doing edge detection first?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the example in openCV documentation?

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html

Answer (score 0):

I m doing something similar, hope these tips could help. I use canny to take the object out, and cut off the background. Then I use SURF in the phase of match, not on the output of canny, but the original image that has been processed based on the output of canny. About the reason why edge fails, I think Misha is right.